# How to get the json key and value in Django's Templating language?

Tags: json, django, django-templates, django-jsonfield

I'm trying to build a website for tv series using Django framework, I put in the models.py all kinds of details about that show and a JSONField to define the number seasons and episodes in each season.
Example: `{ "s1" : 15 , "s2" : 25 , "s3" : 23}`

I made a dropdown in the template where the series is playing so the user can select the episode
the problem starts when I try to access the values of the keys in the JSON object passed.
I tried that:

```
{% for key in show.episodes %}         
    Season {{key}}
        {% for value in show.episodes[{{key}}] %}
            {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it this is not working, I assume that the [0] thing in js doesn't work in Django's Templating language, but I cant seem to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the items with the [**`.items()`** method <sup>[python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

```
{% for key, value in show.episodes.items %}
    Season {{key}}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: cool, but what I mean is that I want to call the number of episodes of the second season.
in js I would do episodes[1].value
how do i do that in Django templating language?
I tried show.episodes.items[1] which surly didn't work

Comment: something like the zip() function in python

Comment: @YoussefIhab: `episodes` is a dictionary and the keys are strings, hence, `episodes[1]` makes no sense, but you can use ``show.episodes.s1` here to access the value for `s1`, subscripting is *deliberately* restricted in the template language to prevent people from wrting business logic in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{key.0}}{{key.1}}
But for this you have to use list of tupples which is I think is a better option to use in django ... Instead of dictionary